# I can't see any database under the data connections node in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have create some Microsoft SQL Server database files before. But I can't see any database under data connections. I want to get the connection string of my databases. Here's a screenshot of my server explorer:

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/GozjF.png

Comment: try expanding the 'server'?

Comment: I used to create tables under the data connections node. But now everything is gone.